# maximally symmetric spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, symmetry, curvature

An empty spacetime has zero or constant Ricci Scalar (depending on the cosmological constant). Is there a theorem which guarantees that such a spacetime should be Minkowski or dS/AdS? In other words, can there be non-uniformly curved spacetimes which are empty everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Schwarzchild metric has $R=0$ and is not maximally symmetric spacetime.

Comment: I mean an empty spacetime everywhere! Schwarzschild spacetime has a central mass!  Are there solutions other than Minkowski, dS and AdS which satisfy Einstein equations everywhere with zero energy momentum tensor?